# How does control of Wintergrasp/Vault of Archavon work?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I try to enter the Vault of Archavon on an alliance character.  Wintergrasp says that it is Alliance controlled.  However, Horde flags appear on the castle and I am unable to zone into the raid.

Also, the zone control event still starts, but no vehicles spawn.

What do I need to do to enter the raid?

Answer (score 2):

Wintergrasp has been especially buggy lately, it appears to have been caused by a recent patch.

What has worked for me and several of my guild mates is to enter Wintergrasp, then log out. After logging back in, it should display correctly for you. If that doesn't fix the issue, try closing the client completely, then logging back in.

This should fix spawning issues (NPCs, Vehicles, etc...) as well as the Vault of Archavon.

[This forum post](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/15141444726) also seems to indicate that the map might not update properly until logging back in while in the zone. It could be possible that the zone is actually Horde-controlled but the map states it is Alliance-controlled.